# java.lang.IllegalStateException: ItemWriter must be provided after updating spring batch to 4.1.1

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, spring-batch-tasklet

Previously, we were using **Spring Batch 3.0.6** and tried to update it to **4.1.1**. I have a job with only an `ItemReader` and an `ItemProcessor` - no `ItermWriter` provided. It was working fine before update.

Now, I am getting:

> `java.lang.IllegalStateException: ItemWriter must be provided.`

What is changed from previous version?

```
    <job id="myJob" parent="baseJob">
        <step id="myStep" parent="baseStep">
            <tasklet>
                <chunk reader="myItemReader" processor="myProcessor"
                       commit-interval="1" skip-limit="100000" retry-limit="1">
                    <skippable-exception-classes>
                        <include class="ExceptionClass"/>
                    </skippable-exception-classes>
                    <retryable-exception-classes>
                        <include class="ExceptionClass"/>
                    </retryable-exception-classes>
                </chunk>
            </tasklet>
            <listeners merge="true">
                <listener ref="promotionListener"/>
                <listener ref="skippableExceptionListener"/>
            </listeners>
        </step>
    </job>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`ItemWriter` become mandatory in [`BATCH-2624`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/979). Based on the information from the issue link , this change takes effect after version `3.0.10` , `4.0.2` and `4.1.0`

If you really do not need an `ItemWriter` , you can implement a dummy one:

```java
public class NoOpItemWriter implements  ItemWriter<Object>{

  @Override
  public void write(List<? extends Object> items) throws Exception {
  }
}
```

And configure to use it:

```xml
<bean id="noOpItemWriter" class="org.foo.bar.NoOpItemWriter"/>

<chunk reader="myItemReader" processor="myProcessor" writer="noOpItemWriter">
    .....           
</chunk>
```